# Any safe yet practical distance between cellphone and body to eliminate radiation risk?

Tags: radiation

Is there a practical minimum distance (i.e. 1 meter?) from the body that you can keep a cell phone where the radiation being emitted is no longer a risk?

Comment: What is the radiation a risk of?

Comment: Maybe an aluminum foil hat ?

Answer (score 1):

The maximum power at which a cell phone may transmit is 1 W (in the US, per FCC rules).

The "health concern" would be that this power would interfere with the tissue of your body. This could be because of heating, or because it somehow causes damage to the molecular structure (DNA). Let's take these claims in turn:

1) re heating: at the frequencies of a cell phone (1900 MHz although that depends on the region / standard), the absorption length in tissue is about 2 cm. In the worst case (max transmit power, in contact with the skin) this give you (1 - 1/e) * 0.5 W in a volume of $\frac12 \frac43 \pi r^3 \approx 16~\rm{cm^3}$ - less than 20 mW per cubic centimeter. By comparison, if you are standing in full sunlight, assuming you absorb half the incident energy (500 W / m^2) in the top 0.5 cm of skin, the local heating would be 100 mW per cubic centimeter. This is something that the body is clearly well capable of dealing with - by adjusting circulation, we prevent heat derived tissue damage (of course in direct sunlight the UV radiation can damage through direct interaction with the electrons).

2) "somehow causing damage". This is a very controversial topic on which the evidence is sketchy. Given that millions of people every day get MRI scans - where they are exposed to kW of RF power over their entire body - with [no convincing evidence](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40134-017-0216-x) that it causes damage. The power levels in cell phones are so much lower that it's hard to see how it would matter.

However - walking around all day with a phone stuck to your ear (or your eyes on the screen) you are at risk of missing out on the world around you; the distraction puts you at significant risk of falling down stairs, walking into traffic, etc. If you are driving, the pull of your attention (and eyes) away from the task of keeping the car on the road and away from other road users / obstacles is a very real threat to your wellbeing. In the USA,

> In 2015 alone, 3,477 people were killed, and 391,000 were injured in motor vehicle crashes involving distracted drivers.

[source](https://www.nhtsa.gov/risky-driving/distracted-driving).

That is a measurable, quantified risk. There is no known death toll from just having a phone close to your body.

Of all the risks of mobile phones, the intensity of their RF emissions is not significant.

Comment: In re the next to last paragraph, IIRC, there's also the growing number of vehicular accidents sure to distracted driving (mostly drivers killing pedestrians)! PSA: Please turn your mobile off when diving!

Comment: @KyleKanos absolutely!!

Comment: Storytime: some customers at the store where I work threw a big fit about some kids near them causing a "dangerous environment" by having their cell phones out. They were ejected from the store and came back the next day to complain to the store manager; I didn't get a chance to ask what they do about the giant nuclear reactor in the sky when they go outside.

Answer (score 0):

There is no evidence that having it on your body poses any risk at all.

So 0 meters would work.

Comment: this is a fine answer but it would drastically improve if you added a reference for your claim that "There is no evidence that having it on your body poses any risk at all."